# How do we assign a custom eviction policy for ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache

I am trying to assign a custom eviction policy (default one's available being LRU/LFU) to ehcache which is in-memory only using net.sf.ehcache.Cache.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy(Policy) method. However, it is not being used by EhCache because it is internally using a [MemoryOnlyStore](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/store/MemoryOnlyStore.html) which has the store as [NullStore](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/store/NullStore.html) and authority as [NotifyingMemoryStore](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/store/NotifyingMemoryStore.html). So, when I try to set the policy, it is setting on the NullStore, which performs a NO-OP. Any idea, how to set a custom eviction policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a bug with ehcache 2.5 version. Refer to this [link](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6515.page) for further information.